# Что происходит в моменте (b & 0xFF) + 0x100)

Tags: java

```
public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] ip = new byte[]{(byte) 192, (byte) 168, 1, 2};
    byte[] mask = new byte[]{(byte) 255, (byte) 255, (byte) 254, 0};
    byte[] netAddress = getNetAddress(ip, mask);
    print(ip);          //11000000 10101000 00000001 00000010
    print(mask);        //11111111 11111111 11111110 00000000
    print(netAddress);  //11000000 10101000 00000000 00000000
}

public static byte[] getNetAddress(byte[] ip, byte[] mask) {
    byte[] res = new byte[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        res[i] = (byte) (ip[i] & mask[i]);
    }

    return res;
}

public static void print(byte[] bytes) {
    for (byte b : bytes) {
        //Byte to binary format
System.out.print(Integer.toBinaryString((b & 0xFF) + 0x100).substring(1)+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

Comment: Вы знакомы c bitwise operators? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Comment: спасибо, разобрался

Answer (score 4):

Уверен, что автор вопроса представляет как работает &. Вопрос наверное почему делается & 0xFF и почему прибавляется 0x100. Ну и почему из получившейся строки нужно выбросить первый символ.

Переведу [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17496691/7459856)

> 0xFF это 255 или 11111111 (максимальное значение для беззнакового
>   байта). 0x100 это 256 или 100000000 (один и восемь нулей - прим. моё).
>   Операция & превращает значение byte в int. В этот момент оно может
>   быть любым в диапазоне 0-255 (00000000 - 11111111, я исключил ведущие
>   24 нуля). + 0x100 и `.substring(1)` гарантирует ведущие нули.

...

Например, `b = 1 (00000001)`. Если применить `Integer.toBinaryString(b)`, число будет без ведущих нулей. Маска 0xFF ограничивает результат диапазоном 0-255 (8 бит), но ведущие нули так и не формируются. Чтобы они сформировались, прибавляем 256 (100000000 - один и восемь нулей) - в результате правые 8 бит не изменятся, но добавится 9-я единица (слева), которую мы отсекаем с помощью `.substring(1)`.

Answer (score -1):

Происходит `and` побитно.
Пример:

```
101 & 111 = 101
100 & 111 = 100
100 & 110 = 100
```